# Start and end of numbers of results elasticsearch river for couchdb

Tags: elasticsearch, couchdb

I can query my results in the following manner. I can control the number of results using size.

```
http://localhost:9200/discogs/discogs/_search?q=artist.name:b*&pretty=true&size=1000
```

But how can I have results starting from one number to another number

I tried finding documentation, but no luck so far. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Using "from" as follows:
    http://localhost:9200/discogs/discogs/_search?q=artist.name:b*&pretty=true&size=100&from=100